# Does PHP have a function that returns the correct file extension given a valid content type?

Tags: php, content-type, file-extension

Does PHP have a function that returns a file extension given a content type?

I'm looking for something that works like:

```
<?php
function getFileExtension($contentType)
{
    if ($contentType === 'image/png')
    {
        return '.png';
    }
    elseif ($contentType === 'image/jpg')
    {
        return '.jpg';
    }
    elseif ($contentType === 'application/zip')
    {
        return '.zip';
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The goal is to use a library function that has all content types handled. Based on the pattern above, I guess I could roll my own with something like this:

```
<?php
function getFileExtension($contentType)
{
    $pieces = explode('/', $contentType);
    return '.' . array_pop($pieces);
}
```

... but that seems janky. Anybody know of an already authored PHP solution? LMK. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the content type? Are you serving these files?

Comment: Have a read through the following: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Comment: @Erik: The OP wants to do the *opposite* of that.

Comment: @MikePurcell I know the content type because the content type is stored in my database with the file's content.

Comment: @Blender A switch statement (with a default) is basically the exact same thing as an if elseif else statement. A switch doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @JohnErck: True, but because you are testing the value of only one var, a switch would be better in this situation.

Comment: @Blender, That's why it's a comment and not an answer

Comment: There are files that can have the same content type, but may well have different extensions (.jpg/.jpeg springs to mind, or .xls/.xlsm)

Comment: @MarkBaker You're correct and this prevents a "definitive" solution... just added more detail regarding this in my final post/answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given the limited number of file types stored within my application's database, the following class/method was an acceptable solution.

```
<?php
class AppUtil
{
    public static function FileExt($contentType)
    {
        $map = array(
            'application/pdf'   => '.pdf',
            'application/zip'   => '.zip',
            'image/gif'         => '.gif',
            'image/jpeg'        => '.jpg',
            'image/png'         => '.png',
            'text/css'          => '.css',
            'text/html'         => '.html',
            'text/javascript'   => '.js',
            'text/plain'        => '.txt',
            'text/xml'          => '.xml',
        );
        if (isset($map[$contentType]))
        {
            return $map[$contentType];
        }

        // HACKISH CATCH ALL (WHICH IN MY CASE IS
        // PREFERRED OVER THROWING AN EXCEPTION)
        $pieces = explode('/', $contentType);
        return '.' . array_pop($pieces);
    }
}

echo AppUtil::FileExt('application/zip'); // prints '.zip'
```

Before settling on the above solution though, I did some searching on Google (as suggested by @whichdan) and found the following "extension to MIME type" mapping resource.

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

After doing some analysis on the data presented in the above URL it became clear that there isn't a definitive solution for this problem (which is probably why there isn't a "content type to file extension" function in PHP).

To illustrate this fact for the benefit of the Stack Overflow community, I parsed the data presented in the above URL and split each content type into one of two categories - either "DEFINITIVE" OR "AMBIGUOUS". Running var_export on each of my "post parse" arrays results in the following PHP code.

```
<?php
// DEFINITIVE "CONTENT TYPE TO FILE EXTENSION" MAPPINGS
$definitive = array (
  'application/x-authorware-bin' => '.aab',
  'application/x-authorware-map' => '.aam',
  'application/x-authorware-seg' => '.aas',
  'text/vnd.abc' => '.abc',
  'video/animaflex' => '.afl',
  'application/x-aim' => '.aim',
  'text/x-audiosoft-intra' => '.aip',
  'application/x-navi-animation' => '.ani',
  'application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software' => '.aos',
  'application/mime' => '.aps',
  'application/arj' => '.arj',
  'image/x-jg' => '.art',
  'text/asp' => '.asp',
  'application/x-mplayer2' => '.asx',
  'video/x-ms-asf-plugin' => '.asx',
  'audio/x-au' => '.au',
  'application/x-troff-msvideo' => '.avi',
  'video/avi' => '.avi',
  'video/msvideo' => '.avi',
  'video/x-msvideo' => '.avi',
  'video/avs-video' => '.avs',
  'application/x-bcpio' => '.bcpio',
  'application/mac-binary' => '.bin',
  'application/macbinary' => '.bin',
  'application/x-binary' => '.bin',
  'application/x-macbinary' => '.bin',
  'image/x-windows-bmp' => '.bmp',
  'application/x-bzip' => '.bz',
  'application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat' => '.cat',
  'application/clariscad' => '.ccad',
  'application/x-cocoa' => '.cco',
  'application/cdf' => '.cdf',
  'application/x-cdf' => '.cdf',
  'application/java' => '.class',
  'application/java-byte-code' => '.class',
  'application/x-java-class' => '.class',
  'application/x-cpio' => '.cpio',
  'application/mac-compactpro' => '.cpt',
  'application/x-compactpro' => '.cpt',
  'application/x-cpt' => '.cpt',
  'application/pkcs-crl' => '.crl',
  'application/pkix-crl' => '.crl',
  'application/x-x509-user-cert' => '.crt',
  'application/x-csh' => '.csh',
  'text/x-script.csh' => '.csh',
  'application/x-pointplus' => '.css',
  'text/css' => '.css',
  'application/x-deepv' => '.deepv',
  'video/dl' => '.dl',
  'video/x-dl' => '.dl',
  'application/commonground' => '.dp',
  'application/drafting' => '.drw',
  'application/x-dvi' => '.dvi',
  'drawing/x-dwf (old)' => '.dwf',
  'model/vnd.dwf' => '.dwf',
  'application/acad' => '.dwg',
  'application/dxf' => '.dxf',
  'text/x-script.elisp' => '.el',
  'application/x-bytecode.elisp (compiled elisp)' => '.elc',
  'application/x-elc' => '.elc',
  'application/x-esrehber' => '.es',
  'text/x-setext' => '.etx',
  'application/envoy' => '.evy',
  'application/vnd.fdf' => '.fdf',
  'application/fractals' => '.fif',
  'image/fif' => '.fif',
  'video/fli' => '.fli',
  'video/x-fli' => '.fli',
  'text/vnd.fmi.flexstor' => '.flx',
  'video/x-atomic3d-feature' => '.fmf',
  'image/vnd.fpx' => '.fpx',
  'image/vnd.net-fpx' => '.fpx',
  'application/freeloader' => '.frl',
  'image/g3fax' => '.g3',
  'image/gif' => '.gif',
  'video/gl' => '.gl',
  'video/x-gl' => '.gl',
  'application/x-gsp' => '.gsp',
  'application/x-gss' => '.gss',
  'application/x-gtar' => '.gtar',
  'multipart/x-gzip' => '.gzip',
  'application/x-hdf' => '.hdf',
  'text/x-script' => '.hlb',
  'application/hlp' => '.hlp',
  'application/x-winhelp' => '.hlp',
  'application/binhex' => '.hqx',
  'application/binhex4' => '.hqx',
  'application/mac-binhex' => '.hqx',
  'application/mac-binhex40' => '.hqx',
  'application/x-binhex40' => '.hqx',
  'application/x-mac-binhex40' => '.hqx',
  'application/hta' => '.hta',
  'text/x-component' => '.htc',
  'text/webviewhtml' => '.htt',
  'x-conference/x-cooltalk' => '.ice ',
  'image/x-icon' => '.ico',
  'application/x-ima' => '.ima',
  'application/x-httpd-imap' => '.imap',
  'application/inf' => '.inf ',
  'application/x-internett-signup' => '.ins',
  'application/x-ip2' => '.ip ',
  'video/x-isvideo' => '.isu',
  'audio/it' => '.it',
  'application/x-inventor' => '.iv',
  'i-world/i-vrml' => '.ivr',
  'application/x-livescreen' => '.ivy',
  'audio/x-jam' => '.jam ',
  'application/x-java-commerce' => '.jcm ',
  'image/x-jps' => '.jps',
  'application/x-javascript' => '.js ',
  'image/jutvision' => '.jut',
  'music/x-karaoke' => '.kar',
  'application/x-ksh' => '.ksh',
  'text/x-script.ksh' => '.ksh',
  'audio/x-liveaudio' => '.lam',
  'application/lha' => '.lha',
  'application/x-lha' => '.lha',
  'application/x-lisp' => '.lsp ',
  'text/x-script.lisp' => '.lsp ',
  'text/x-la-asf' => '.lsx',
  'application/x-lzh' => '.lzh',
  'application/lzx' => '.lzx',
  'application/x-lzx' => '.lzx',
  'text/x-m' => '.m',
  'audio/x-mpequrl' => '.m3u ',
  'application/x-troff-man' => '.man',
  'application/x-navimap' => '.map',
  'application/mbedlet' => '.mbd',
  'application/x-magic-cap-package-1.0' => '.mc$',
  'application/mcad' => '.mcd',
  'application/x-mathcad' => '.mcd',
  'image/vasa' => '.mcf',
  'text/mcf' => '.mcf',
  'application/netmc' => '.mcp',
  'application/x-troff-me' => '.me ',
  'application/x-frame' => '.mif',
  'application/x-mif' => '.mif',
  'www/mime' => '.mime ',
  'audio/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mjuicemediafile' => '.mjf',
  'video/x-motion-jpeg' => '.mjpg ',
  'application/x-meme' => '.mm',
  'audio/mod' => '.mod',
  'audio/x-mod' => '.mod',
  'audio/x-mpeg' => '.mp2',
  'video/x-mpeq2a' => '.mp2',
  'audio/mpeg3' => '.mp3',
  'audio/x-mpeg-3' => '.mp3',
  'application/vnd.ms-project' => '.mpp',
  'application/marc' => '.mrc',
  'application/x-troff-ms' => '.ms',
  'application/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mzz' => '.mzz',
  'application/vnd.nokia.configuration-message' => '.ncm',
  'application/x-mix-transfer' => '.nix',
  'application/x-conference' => '.nsc',
  'application/x-navidoc' => '.nvd',
  'application/oda' => '.oda',
  'application/x-omc' => '.omc',
  'application/x-omcdatamaker' => '.omcd',
  'application/x-omcregerator' => '.omcr',
  'text/x-pascal' => '.p',
  'application/pkcs10' => '.p10',
  'application/x-pkcs10' => '.p10',
  'application/pkcs-12' => '.p12',
  'application/x-pkcs12' => '.p12',
  'application/x-pkcs7-signature' => '.p7a',
  'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp' => '.p7r',
  'application/pkcs7-signature' => '.p7s',
  'text/pascal' => '.pas',
  'image/x-portable-bitmap' => '.pbm ',
  'application/vnd.hp-pcl' => '.pcl',
  'application/x-pcl' => '.pcl',
  'image/x-pict' => '.pct',
  'image/x-pcx' => '.pcx',
  'application/pdf' => '.pdf',
  'audio/make.my.funk' => '.pfunk',
  'image/x-portable-graymap' => '.pgm',
  'image/x-portable-greymap' => '.pgm',
  'application/x-newton-compatible-pkg' => '.pkg',
  'application/vnd.ms-pki.pko' => '.pko',
  'text/x-script.perl' => '.pl',
  'application/x-pixclscript' => '.plx',
  'text/x-script.perl-module' => '.pm',
  'application/x-portable-anymap' => '.pnm',
  'image/x-portable-anymap' => '.pnm',
  'model/x-pov' => '.pov',
  'image/x-portable-pixmap' => '.ppm',
  'application/powerpoint' => '.ppt',
  'application/x-mspowerpoint' => '.ppt',
  'application/x-freelance' => '.pre',
  'paleovu/x-pv' => '.pvu',
  'text/x-script.phyton' => '.py ',
  'applicaiton/x-bytecode.python' => '.pyc ',
  'audio/vnd.qcelp' => '.qcp ',
  'video/x-qtc' => '.qtc',
  'audio/x-realaudio' => '.ra',
  'application/x-cmu-raster' => '.ras',
  'image/x-cmu-raster' => '.ras',
  'text/x-script.rexx' => '.rexx ',
  'image/vnd.rn-realflash' => '.rf',
  'image/x-rgb' => '.rgb ',
  'application/vnd.rn-realmedia' => '.rm',
  'audio/mid' => '.rmi',
  'application/ringing-tones' => '.rng',
  'application/vnd.nokia.ringing-tone' => '.rng',
  'application/vnd.rn-realplayer' => '.rnx ',
  'image/vnd.rn-realpix' => '.rp ',
  'text/vnd.rn-realtext' => '.rt',
  'application/x-rtf' => '.rtf',
  'video/vnd.rn-realvideo' => '.rv',
  'audio/s3m' => '.s3m ',
  'application/x-lotusscreencam' => '.scm',
  'text/x-script.guile' => '.scm',
  'text/x-script.scheme' => '.scm',
  'video/x-scm' => '.scm',
  'application/sdp' => '.sdp ',
  'application/x-sdp' => '.sdp ',
  'application/sounder' => '.sdr',
  'application/sea' => '.sea',
  'application/x-sea' => '.sea',
  'application/set' => '.set',
  'application/x-sh' => '.sh',
  'text/x-script.sh' => '.sh',
  'audio/x-psid' => '.sid',
  'application/x-sit' => '.sit',
  'application/x-stuffit' => '.sit',
  'application/x-seelogo' => '.sl ',
  'audio/x-adpcm' => '.snd',
  'application/solids' => '.sol',
  'application/x-pkcs7-certificates' => '.spc ',
  'application/futuresplash' => '.spl',
  'application/streamingmedia' => '.ssm ',
  'application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore' => '.sst',
  'application/sla' => '.stl',
  'application/vnd.ms-pki.stl' => '.stl',
  'application/x-navistyle' => '.stl',
  'application/x-sv4cpio' => '.sv4cpio',
  'application/x-sv4crc' => '.sv4crc',
  'x-world/x-svr' => '.svr',
  'application/x-shockwave-flash' => '.swf',
  'application/x-tar' => '.tar',
  'application/toolbook' => '.tbk',
  'application/x-tcl' => '.tcl',
  'text/x-script.tcl' => '.tcl',
  'text/x-script.tcsh' => '.tcsh',
  'application/x-tex' => '.tex',
  'application/plain' => '.text',
  'application/gnutar' => '.tgz',
  'audio/tsp-audio' => '.tsi',
  'application/dsptype' => '.tsp',
  'audio/tsplayer' => '.tsp',
  'text/tab-separated-values' => '.tsv',
  'text/x-uil' => '.uil',
  'application/i-deas' => '.unv',
  'application/x-ustar' => '.ustar',
  'multipart/x-ustar' => '.ustar',
  'application/x-cdlink' => '.vcd',
  'text/x-vcalendar' => '.vcs',
  'application/vda' => '.vda',
  'video/vdo' => '.vdo',
  'application/groupwise' => '.vew ',
  'application/vocaltec-media-desc' => '.vmd ',
  'application/vocaltec-media-file' => '.vmf',
  'audio/voc' => '.voc',
  'audio/x-voc' => '.voc',
  'video/vosaic' => '.vos',
  'audio/voxware' => '.vox',
  'audio/x-twinvq' => '.vqf',
  'application/x-vrml' => '.vrml',
  'x-world/x-vrt' => '.vrt',
  'application/wordperfect6.1' => '.w61',
  'audio/wav' => '.wav',
  'audio/x-wav' => '.wav',
  'application/x-qpro' => '.wb1',
  'image/vnd.wap.wbmp' => '.wbmp',
  'application/vnd.xara' => '.web',
  'application/x-123' => '.wk1',
  'windows/metafile' => '.wmf',
  'text/vnd.wap.wml' => '.wml',
  'application/vnd.wap.wmlc' => '.wmlc ',
  'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript' => '.wmls',
  'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc' => '.wmlsc ',
  'application/x-wpwin' => '.wpd',
  'application/x-lotus' => '.wq1',
  'application/mswrite' => '.wri',
  'application/x-wri' => '.wri',
  'text/scriplet' => '.wsc',
  'application/x-wintalk' => '.wtk ',
  'image/x-xbitmap' => '.xbm',
  'image/x-xbm' => '.xbm',
  'image/xbm' => '.xbm',
  'video/x-amt-demorun' => '.xdr',
  'xgl/drawing' => '.xgz',
  'image/vnd.xiff' => '.xif',
  'audio/xm' => '.xm',
  'application/xml' => '.xml',
  'text/xml' => '.xml',
  'xgl/movie' => '.xmz',
  'application/x-vnd.ls-xpix' => '.xpix',
  'image/xpm' => '.xpm',
  'video/x-amt-showrun' => '.xsr',
  'image/x-xwd' => '.xwd',
  'image/x-xwindowdump' => '.xwd',
  'application/x-compress' => '.z',
  'application/x-zip-compressed' => '.zip',
  'application/zip' => '.zip',
  'multipart/x-zip' => '.zip',
  'text/x-script.zsh' => '.zsh',
);
```

...and...

```
<?php
// AMBIGUOUS "CONTENT TYPE TO FILE EXTENSION" MAPPINGS
$ambiguous = array (
  'x-world/x-3dmf' => 
  array (
    0 => '.3dm',
    1 => '.3dmf',
    2 => '.qd3 ',
    3 => '.qd3d ',
  ),
  'application/octet-stream' => 
  array (
    0 => '.a',
    1 => '.arc',
    2 => '.arj',
    3 => '.bin',
    4 => '.com',
    5 => '.dump',
    6 => '.exe',
    7 => '.lha',
    8 => '.lhx',
    9 => '.lzh',
    10 => '.lzx',
    11 => '.o',
    12 => '.psd',
    13 => '.saveme',
    14 => '.uu',
    15 => '.zoo',
  ),
  'text/html' => 
  array (
    0 => '.acgi',
    1 => '.htm',
    2 => '.html',
    3 => '.htmls',
    4 => '.htx ',
    5 => '.shtml ',
  ),
  'application/postscript' => 
  array (
    0 => '.ai',
    1 => '.eps',
    2 => '.ps',
  ),
  'audio/aiff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.aif',
    1 => '.aifc',
    2 => '.aiff',
  ),
  'audio/x-aiff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.aif',
    1 => '.aifc',
    2 => '.aiff',
  ),
  'video/x-ms-asf' => 
  array (
    0 => '.asf',
    1 => '.asx',
  ),
  'text/x-asm' => 
  array (
    0 => '.asm',
    1 => '.s',
  ),
  'audio/basic' => 
  array (
    0 => '.au',
    1 => '.snd',
  ),
  'image/bmp' => 
  array (
    0 => '.bm',
    1 => '.bmp',
  ),
  'application/book' => 
  array (
    0 => '.boo',
    1 => '.book',
  ),
  'application/x-bzip2' => 
  array (
    0 => '.boz',
    1 => '.bz2',
  ),
  'application/x-bsh' => 
  array (
    0 => '.bsh',
    1 => '.sh',
    2 => '.shar',
  ),
  'text/plain' => 
  array (
    0 => '.c',
    1 => '.c++',
    2 => '.cc',
    3 => '.com',
    4 => '.conf',
    5 => '.cxx',
    6 => '.def',
    7 => '.f',
    8 => '.f90',
    9 => '.for',
    10 => '.g',
    11 => '.h',
    12 => '.hh',
    13 => '.idc',
    14 => '.jav',
    15 => '.java',
    16 => '.list',
    17 => '.log ',
    18 => '.lst ',
    19 => '.m',
    20 => '.mar',
    21 => '.pl',
    22 => '.sdml',
    23 => '.text',
    24 => '.txt',
  ),
  'text/x-c' => 
  array (
    0 => '.c',
    1 => '.cc',
    2 => '.cpp',
  ),
  'application/x-netcdf' => 
  array (
    0 => '.cdf',
    1 => '.nc',
  ),
  'application/pkix-cert' => 
  array (
    0 => '.cer',
    1 => '.crt',
  ),
  'application/x-x509-ca-cert' => 
  array (
    0 => '.cer',
    1 => '.crt',
    2 => '.der',
  ),
  'application/x-chat' => 
  array (
    0 => '.cha',
    1 => '.chat',
  ),
  'application/x-director' => 
  array (
    0 => '.dcr',
    1 => '.dir',
    2 => '.dxr',
  ),
  'video/x-dv' => 
  array (
    0 => '.dif',
    1 => '.dv',
  ),
  'application/msword' => 
  array (
    0 => '.doc',
    1 => '.dot',
    2 => '.w6w',
    3 => '.wiz',
    4 => '.word ',
  ),
  'image/vnd.dwg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.dwg',
    1 => '.dxf',
    2 => '.svf',
  ),
  'image/x-dwg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.dwg',
    1 => '.dxf',
    2 => '.svf',
  ),
  'application/x-envoy' => 
  array (
    0 => '.env',
    1 => '.evy',
  ),
  'text/x-fortran' => 
  array (
    0 => '.f',
    1 => '.f77',
    2 => '.f90',
    3 => '.for',
  ),
  'image/florian' => 
  array (
    0 => '.flo',
    1 => '.turbot',
  ),
  'audio/make' => 
  array (
    0 => '.funk',
    1 => '.my',
    2 => '.pfunk',
  ),
  'audio/x-gsm' => 
  array (
    0 => '.gsd',
    1 => '.gsm',
  ),
  'application/x-compressed' => 
  array (
    0 => '.gz',
    1 => '.tgz',
    2 => '.z',
    3 => '.zip',
  ),
  'application/x-gzip' => 
  array (
    0 => '.gz',
    1 => '.gzip',
  ),
  'text/x-h' => 
  array (
    0 => '.h',
    1 => '.hh',
  ),
  'application/x-helpfile' => 
  array (
    0 => '.help',
    1 => '.hlp',
  ),
  'application/vnd.hp-hpgl' => 
  array (
    0 => '.hgl',
    1 => '.hpg',
    2 => '.hpgl',
  ),
  'image/ief' => 
  array (
    0 => '.ief',
    1 => '.iefs',
  ),
  'application/iges' => 
  array (
    0 => '.iges',
    1 => '.igs',
  ),
  'model/iges' => 
  array (
    0 => '.iges ',
    1 => '.igs',
  ),
  'text/x-java-source' => 
  array (
    0 => '.jav',
    1 => '.java ',
  ),
  'image/jpeg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.jfif',
    1 => '.jfif-tbnl',
    2 => '.jpe',
    3 => '.jpeg',
    4 => '.jpg ',
  ),
  'image/pjpeg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.jfif',
    1 => '.jpe',
    2 => '.jpeg',
    3 => '.jpg ',
  ),
  'audio/midi' => 
  array (
    0 => '.kar',
    1 => '.mid',
    2 => '.midi',
  ),
  'audio/nspaudio' => 
  array (
    0 => '.la ',
    1 => '.lma',
  ),
  'audio/x-nspaudio' => 
  array (
    0 => '.la ',
    1 => '.lma',
  ),
  'application/x-latex' => 
  array (
    0 => '.latex ',
    1 => '.ltx',
  ),
  'video/mpeg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.m1v',
    1 => '.m2v',
    2 => '.mp2',
    3 => '.mp3',
    4 => '.mpa',
    5 => '.mpe',
    6 => '.mpeg',
    7 => '.mpg',
  ),
  'audio/mpeg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.m2a',
    1 => '.mp2',
    2 => '.mpa',
    3 => '.mpg',
    4 => '.mpga',
  ),
  'message/rfc822' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mht',
    1 => '.mhtml',
    2 => '.mime ',
  ),
  'application/x-midi' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mid',
    1 => '.midi',
  ),
  'audio/x-mid' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mid',
    1 => '.midi',
  ),
  'audio/x-midi' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mid',
    1 => '.midi',
  ),
  'music/crescendo' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mid',
    1 => '.midi',
  ),
  'x-music/x-midi' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mid',
    1 => '.midi',
  ),
  'application/base64' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mm',
    1 => '.mme',
  ),
  'video/quicktime' => 
  array (
    0 => '.moov',
    1 => '.mov',
    2 => '.qt',
  ),
  'video/x-sgi-movie' => 
  array (
    0 => '.movie',
    1 => '.mv',
  ),
  'video/x-mpeg' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mp2',
    1 => '.mp3',
  ),
  'application/x-project' => 
  array (
    0 => '.mpc',
    1 => '.mpt',
    2 => '.mpv',
    3 => '.mpx',
  ),
  'image/naplps' => 
  array (
    0 => '.nap',
    1 => '.naplps',
  ),
  'image/x-niff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.nif',
    1 => '.niff',
  ),
  'application/pkcs7-mime' => 
  array (
    0 => '.p7c',
    1 => '.p7m',
  ),
  'application/x-pkcs7-mime' => 
  array (
    0 => '.p7c',
    1 => '.p7m',
  ),
  'application/pro_eng' => 
  array (
    0 => '.part ',
    1 => '.prt',
  ),
  'chemical/x-pdb' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pdb',
    1 => '.xyz',
  ),
  'image/pict' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pic',
    1 => '.pict',
  ),
  'image/x-xpixmap' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pm',
    1 => '.xpm',
  ),
  'application/x-pagemaker' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pm4 ',
    1 => '.pm5',
  ),
  'image/png' => 
  array (
    0 => '.png',
    1 => '.x-png',
  ),
  'application/mspowerpoint' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pot',
    1 => '.pps',
    2 => '.ppt',
    3 => '.ppz',
  ),
  'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' => 
  array (
    0 => '.pot',
    1 => '.ppa',
    2 => '.pps',
    3 => '.ppt',
    4 => '.pwz ',
  ),
  'image/x-quicktime' => 
  array (
    0 => '.qif',
    1 => '.qti',
    2 => '.qtif',
  ),
  'audio/x-pn-realaudio' => 
  array (
    0 => '.ra',
    1 => '.ram',
    2 => '.rm',
    3 => '.rmm ',
    4 => '.rmp',
  ),
  'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin' => 
  array (
    0 => '.ra',
    1 => '.rmp',
    2 => '.rpm',
  ),
  'image/cmu-raster' => 
  array (
    0 => '.ras',
    1 => '.rast',
  ),
  'application/x-troff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.roff',
    1 => '.t',
    2 => '.tr',
  ),
  'text/richtext' => 
  array (
    0 => '.rt',
    1 => '.rtf',
    2 => '.rtx',
  ),
  'application/rtf' => 
  array (
    0 => '.rtf',
    1 => '.rtx',
  ),
  'application/x-tbook' => 
  array (
    0 => '.sbk ',
    1 => '.tbk',
  ),
  'text/sgml' => 
  array (
    0 => '.sgm ',
    1 => '.sgml',
  ),
  'text/x-sgml' => 
  array (
    0 => '.sgm ',
    1 => '.sgml',
  ),
  'application/x-shar' => 
  array (
    0 => '.sh',
    1 => '.shar',
  ),
  'text/x-server-parsed-html' => 
  array (
    0 => '.shtml',
    1 => '.ssi',
  ),
  'application/x-koan' => 
  array (
    0 => '.skd',
    1 => '.skm ',
    2 => '.skp ',
    3 => '.skt ',
  ),
  'application/smil' => 
  array (
    0 => '.smi ',
    1 => '.smil ',
  ),
  'text/x-speech' => 
  array (
    0 => '.spc ',
    1 => '.talk',
  ),
  'application/x-sprite' => 
  array (
    0 => '.spr',
    1 => '.sprite ',
  ),
  'application/x-wais-source' => 
  array (
    0 => '.src',
    1 => '.wsrc',
  ),
  'application/step' => 
  array (
    0 => '.step',
    1 => '.stp',
  ),
  'application/x-world' => 
  array (
    0 => '.svr',
    1 => '.wrl',
  ),
  'application/x-texinfo' => 
  array (
    0 => '.texi',
    1 => '.texinfo',
  ),
  'image/tiff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.tif',
    1 => '.tiff',
  ),
  'image/x-tiff' => 
  array (
    0 => '.tif',
    1 => '.tiff',
  ),
  'text/uri-list' => 
  array (
    0 => '.uni',
    1 => '.unis',
    2 => '.uri',
    3 => '.uris',
  ),
  'text/x-uuencode' => 
  array (
    0 => '.uu',
    1 => '.uue',
  ),
  'video/vivo' => 
  array (
    0 => '.viv',
    1 => '.vivo',
  ),
  'video/vnd.vivo' => 
  array (
    0 => '.viv',
    1 => '.vivo',
  ),
  'audio/x-twinvq-plugin' => 
  array (
    0 => '.vqe',
    1 => '.vql',
  ),
  'model/vrml' => 
  array (
    0 => '.vrml',
    1 => '.wrl',
    2 => '.wrz',
  ),
  'x-world/x-vrml' => 
  array (
    0 => '.vrml',
    1 => '.wrl',
    2 => '.wrz',
  ),
  'application/x-visio' => 
  array (
    0 => '.vsd',
    1 => '.vst',
    2 => '.vsw ',
  ),
  'application/wordperfect6.0' => 
  array (
    0 => '.w60',
    1 => '.wp5',
  ),
  'application/wordperfect' => 
  array (
    0 => '.wp',
    1 => '.wp5',
    2 => '.wp6 ',
    3 => '.wpd',
  ),
  'application/excel' => 
  array (
    0 => '.xl',
    1 => '.xla',
    2 => '.xlb',
    3 => '.xlc',
    4 => '.xld ',
    5 => '.xlk',
    6 => '.xll',
    7 => '.xlm',
    8 => '.xls',
    9 => '.xlt',
    10 => '.xlv',
    11 => '.xlw',
  ),
  'application/x-excel' => 
  array (
    0 => '.xla',
    1 => '.xlb',
    2 => '.xlc',
    3 => '.xld ',
    4 => '.xlk',
    5 => '.xll',
    6 => '.xlm',
    7 => '.xls',
    8 => '.xlt',
    9 => '.xlv',
    10 => '.xlw',
  ),
  'application/x-msexcel' => 
  array (
    0 => '.xla',
    1 => '.xls',
    2 => '.xlw',
  ),
  'application/vnd.ms-excel' => 
  array (
    0 => '.xlb',
    1 => '.xlc',
    2 => '.xll',
    3 => '.xlm',
    4 => '.xls',
    5 => '.xlw',
  ),
);
```

Comment: You should not put the dot in every value, you'll only end up missing it somewhere and it adds extra noise to your code. Concatenate the dot with the extension either in the return statement or in the place where you build the file name.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to create your own class to handle this.

[Google search for "mimetype file extension list"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=mimetype+file+extension+list)

Create a static class with a mimetype => extension list stored in an array, and then write a findByMimeType and findByExtension method. You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) to search by value.