# Is there a way to know the file type with only the data

Tags: php

For some technical issues, I cannot send a file from my input to my backend the traditional way. I have to read the data from the file, bind that to a model and send that data (as a huge string) to the server. Let's say that my user upload a .jpg, my code looks like this :

```
// This return the data in the form of a simple string.
$data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('document[document_file]', null, true);

// Let's assume that I know what type of file my user send me
$data = explode("data:image/jpeg;base64,", $file);
$data = base64_decode($data[1]);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

imagejpeg($image, "test.jpg");
```

My problem is that I have no idea what type of file my user will upload. Is there a way to find out what type of file it is and save it in a more efficient way. What's the more efficient way of dealing with such an issue?

EDIT: One thing to note is that it's not always an image. It can be a .pdf, .doc, .txt!

Comment: Try looking at fileinfo extension : http://php.net/manual/pl/book.fileinfo.php , or if you expect images, you can try checking file using `imagecreatefromstring()`, `getimagesizefromstring()` etc and check for errors.

Comment: @piotrekkr I don't know if it's an image, it could be a .doc, .txt, .pdf, I'll take a look at fileinfo

Comment: I wrote `if you expect image`, not if you are sure :)

Comment: You can always pipe the file through `file` and read the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the image's contents in a string, you can use [`getimagesizefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) which contains a `mime` field that will tell you the type of the image.

```
$data = base64_decode($data[1]);
$info = getimagesizefromstring($data);
$mime = $info['mime'];
```

If you need support for *any* file, not just images, you'll need to either write a custom file parser or, if you have the `FileInfo` PECL extension, you can use [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php):

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, '/path/to/your/file.jpg');
finfo_close($finfo);
```

The caveat to this is that you need an actual file, not a string (but you could always write the string to a temporary file).

EDIT:
Here's the answer to solve the question without the need of a file being created. Let's take the following data from an image:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA [...] xD5epeRHJ4glkjk/sb7R5lrFJ5fmfu/wDv5W1TEV/5wp+58
```

You would need to first parse it first

```
$data = explode(",", $data);
```

Then insert the string in the buffer

```
$finfo->buffer(base64_decode($data[1]))
```

Finally, use [the answer from @JohnErck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967281/does-php-have-a-function-that-returns-the-correct-file-extension-given-a-valid-c) to solve the extension type.

```
file_put_contents($path . $filename . AppUtil::FileExt($data[1]), $data[1]);
```

Comment: So I would save the file with no extension, then read it from finfo and would deduct the extension from that?

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve Yeah; file-types aren't solely dependent on the file's extension (for instance, you can save a jpeg as `img.png` and it will still open/render fine). *Almost* all files have headers in them that declare what their actual file-type is.

Comment: I'm on it, will get back to you with result, thanks for your time (no idea why someone downvoted you!)

Comment: You mind if I edit your answer, it's working but I would make a few modification for future user that would experience this issue?

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve Feel free; make any changes to it that were necessary to solve your problem that could also help out others =]

Answer (score 0):

The Unix tool "file" will tell you what a file is based on the "magic number" at the beginning - maybe you could fork/shell/call that?

Example:

```
file sem.pl sean.zip Windows.pdf
sem.pl:   a /usr/bin/perl script text executable
sean.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
Windows.pdf: PDF document, version 1.5
```